# How to setup a view for adding multiple records to db C# MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm building an intranet site and I need to get a form to be able to add n number of rows. I know how to scaffold a single item create form, but for my purposes when adding to this entity, it will almost always be multiple records. My web searches thus far have returned controller functions to adding records to the db, which I'm already able to do, the piece I'm missing is setting up the form. Any input would be appreciated. I don't have sample code for this because I'm not even certain where to start with this view.

Comment: Usually, if user want to insert many rows at once, we create a module for them to upload excel/csv file.

Comment: No way to scaffold this but if you want to use plugin for the UI part, you can take a look at Jquery Datatables Editor https://editor.datatables.net/